# Reference to STL Vector Type

Tags: c++, stl, reference, vector

I am using someone elses function that takes:

```
optimise(std::vector<double> &input)
```

It edits the input.

How should I pass a vector to this, I have tried:

```
std::vector<double> input;
input.push_back('several points');
optimise(input);
```

This has a linker error saying:

```
undefined reference to optimise(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)
```

If i try this:

```
 std::vector<double> &input;
input.push_back('several points');
optimise(input);
```

Then there is a compile error:

```
'input' declared as reference but not initialised
```

How do I initialise a reference to the vector or am I doing something completely wrong. 
EDIT:

I wasn't linking a library correctly in my CMakeLists. Thanks for everyone's help, i wish i could mark you all as correct.

Comment: It appears you're not linking properly the library or source file that defines this function.

Comment: Your first attempt is correct, so your problem is with the availability of `optimise` rather than the way you call it. Can you post your declaration and definition of `optimise`?

Comment: This appears to be a linker error, not a compiler error. Can you tell us more about how you build your application? Which platform, which tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first way of passing the `vector` is correct. The compiler recognizes that the vector is passed to the function by reference from the signature in the header, makes a reference to your vector, and passes it to the function. The fact that you see linker errors tells you that the compile stage completed successfully.

The linker error is there because you are failing to include the library where the `optimise` function is implemented.

Comment: I thought that, but i use other stuff from the same library and it doesn't have an issue, so i am including the correct header file.

Comment: Would it help if i said the optimise function is part of a class, i initialise that class (lets call the object optimiser) that works fine. Then i use the class optimiser.optimise(input) which doesn't work fine.

Comment: @Ben You are definitely including the right header file: otherwise, the compile would have failed. But you are not linking with the correct library (the `-l`<some-lib> in your compile command is missing).

Comment: @Ben "Then i use the class optimiser.optimise(input) which doesn't work fine." The most likely reason for that is that the constructor of the optimizer class is in the header, but the implementation of `optimizer::optimize` is in the library. Check with the library manual for the name of the library that you need to link (it's usually `lib<some-name>.so` or `.lib` on unix/linux/mac.)

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt appears to fail due to some linker error. You must ensure that the function you call is actually available to the linker, either in some kind of library, or as a separate translation unit (source file), or similar. Just including the header is enough for the compiler, but won't help the linker.

> 'input' declared as reference but not initialised

This makes sense: a reference is always a reference to some object which exists elsewhere. So you cannot use a reference without first telling it what to refer to. The most common case is using references as function arguments. Usually the object would be a normal non-reference object in the scope of the caller, and passed to the callee via reference to avoid copying. In that respect, your first attempt is correct.

Comment: That is correct but i am having a problem now with why its not linking correctly. See the Edited Question.